# Is It Necessary to Add Days of Year Where The Count Was Zero? (Crime Analysis in R)

Tags: r

I'm analyzing crime in a district of Baltimore (5 years of data). I'm creating line charts for specific crime types in specific neighborhoods within the district.  However, not all crime types are reported every day in each neighborhood.  Therefore, there are no days in the data with a count of zero.  There are only those days when crimes were reported in the data.  This visually affects the line chart data touching the x-axis at zero.  Does this negatively affect the trend lines created by stat_smooth in order to identify increases/decreases in crime types?

Reproducible code to produce the line chart:

```
#Read crime data from GitHub repo into a R dataframe
df = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brianthomasbaker/Baltimore-Crime-Analysis/master/Baltimore_SE_Reported_Crime_2010_to_2014.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",")

#Format CrimeDate column
df$CrimeDate = as.Date(df$CrimeDate, "%m/%d/%Y")

#Create new dataframe of only Larceny From Auto crimes by Day of the Year in Canton (2010-2014)
library(dplyr)
df_cantonlarcauto = df %>%
  filter(Neighborhood == "Canton", Description == "LARCENY FROM AUTO") %>%
  group_by(CrimeDate) %>%
  summarize(crimes = n())

#Create Line Chart using ggplot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_cantonlarcauto, aes(x = CrimeDate, y = crimes, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_size_area() +
  stat_smooth(method = "gam") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Number of Crimes") +
  ylim(0,13) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=32, hjust=0)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22)) +
  ggtitle("Larceny From Auto\nCanton (2010-2014)")

head(df_cantonlarcauto)
```

You can see in the header of the dataframe that the 2nd and 3rd of January are missing.  Should missing days and zero counts for those days be added into the data?  If so, how can you do it in R?  Or does the omission of these days not negatively affect attempts to analyze crime data over time?

Comment: I think this may be worse than you think -- the line never drops to 0; instead it is filled in between the 1 values -- if you set `scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:10)` you'll see what I mean.

Comment: From playing with `stat_smooth` and `predict(gam(...))`, it appears that using `NA` or missing values substantially affects the smoothing.  I think from a data analysis perspective, you have to impute a `0` into the missing values, since they aren't missing, but are present with value `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the missing dates with:

```
library(dplyr)
df_cantonlarcauto_missing = data_frame(CrimeDate = seq(min(df_cantonlarcauto$CrimeDate), max(df_cantonlarcauto$CrimeDate), 1)) %>% 
  left_join(df_cantonlarcauto)
```

And if you plot using this dataframe (ggplot(df_cantonlarcauto_missing, aes(x = CrimeDate, y = crimes, group=1)) + ... ) you should already see a better looking plot.

I don't know this data but my personal suggestion watching at it now it's to force to 0 the missing dates and then do some kind of aggregation (like weekly rolling mean) since the values are very low and often missing/0:

```
df_cantonlarcauto_missing = data_frame(CrimeDate = seq(min(df_cantonlarcauto$CrimeDate), max(df_cantonlarcauto$CrimeDate), 1)) %>% 
  left_join(df_cantonlarcauto) %>% 
  mutate(crimes = ifelse(is.na(crimes), 0, crimes)) %>% 
  mutate(crimes = c(rep(NA, 6), rollmean(crimes, 7, align = "right")))

ggplot(df_cantonlarcauto_missing, aes(x = CrimeDate, y = crimes, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_size_area() +
  stat_smooth(method = "gam") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Number of Crimes") +
  # ylim(0,13) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=32, hjust=0)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22)) +
  ggtitle("Larceny From Auto\nCanton (2010-2014)")
```

[image: Plot with Rolling Mean]

Comment: Well your great mind thinks 26 seconds faster than mine :-)

Comment: Adding in the missing dates as "NA", stat_smooth removes the rows containing the missing values.

Comment: Thanks.  Implementing a rolling weekly mean only produces (in this case) 6 rows containing missing values.

Comment: @LorenzoRossi for some reason, I think `mutate(crimes = c(rep(NA, 6), rollmean(crimes, 7, align = "right")))` is forcing the first 6 rows to overwrite values with a 0.  Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Weekly Rolling mean is defined as the average value of 7 consecutive days. For the first 6 dates in your dataframe there will therefore not be a valid value of rolled mean since you don't have enough dates on which to calculate the weekly roll mean. From day 7 you'll have enough historic dates to correctly calculate the rolled mean. That's the reason why in my mutate I explicitly force my first 6 values to be NA.

Comment: @LorenzoRossi So, there's never a way to include the first six days of data when doing a weekly rolling mean?  In my case, missing six days out of hundreds doesn't really matter.  But, if you only have a 10-15 weeks of data, then it seems that omitting the first six days may skew the results.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a full sequence of dates and add NAs for datums that have no crimes to their name. Here's a dirty way of doing it:

```
xy <- data.frame(CrimeDate = seq(df_cantonlarcauto$CrimeDate[1], to = df_cantonlarcauto$CrimeDate[nrow(df_cantonlarcauto)], by = 1))
xy <- merge(xy, df_cantonlarcauto, all.x = TRUE)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = CrimeDate, y = crimes, group=1)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_size_area() +
    stat_smooth(method = "gam") +
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("Number of Crimes") +
    ylim(0,13) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=32, hjust=0)) +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=22)) +
    ggtitle("Larceny From Auto\nCanton (2010-2014)")
```

[image]